# Bootstrap Tabs with Next Arrow If Multiple tabs exist

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I hope someone will be able to help me on this issue. I'm having hard time converting it to latest bootstrap 4 tabs.

Here's the source: https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm

But the problem is that it used the bootstrap 3 version and it doesn't have tab content.

Basically what i need to do is this
[image]

If there's a multiple tabs you can click the arrow to slide to another tabs, just like in the browser

This is where i want to do

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you out

assign `data-id` to anchor tags with number like

**HTML**
Home
Home
Home

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var maxTabs = $(".nav-item").length; //Get total number of Tabs
   $("#next").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var activeAnchor = $("ul").find("a").hasClass("active"); //Get a tag with class active
       // OR you can use var activeAnchor = $("li > a").hasClass("active");
       if(activeAnchor === true){ // check if any "a" has class "active"
            $(this).removeClass("active"); // remove "active" class for current element
            var current = $(this).attr("data-id"); // get the data-id of current element
            if(current < maxTabs){ // checks if id is the last one
                var nextId = current + 1; //adding 1 to current id to get the next element
                $("#nextId").addClass("active"); //Adding the active class to next element
            }
       }
   });
});
```

Please let me know if it works. I am not sure but maybe you encounter problem on line `$(this).removeClass("active");`. If you come across this issue. Please let me know I will provide an alternative solution.

Comment: doesn't work, arrow is not appearing when there's a 5 more tabs